# Create Checkbox with label in ios Appcelerator

Tags: javascript, ios, appcelerator-mobile, appcelerator-titanium

I have a doubt in Appcelerator. Currently i am working with appcelerator for apple devices. What i want now is that to create a check box like android in IOS. By default in android, if we click on check-box in appcelerator android, we can add text on and off for check-box click and it works fine. But in case of IOS, it shows as just on off toggle button with not text. What i need is that, have to show a text when switch is on or off in IOS. Does anybody have any idea about this ? Kindly help me please. Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's a widget I created for the old training course. It's pretty old and probably will need some updating. But it will give you a starting point.

https://github.com/appcelerator-training/tce_training/tree/master/labcode/Finished_code/06_customui/app/widgets/checkbox